# Trying to connect the Shopify app using Shopify connect is throwing an error

Tags: ruby, shopify, mern, shopify-app, web-deployment-project

I have successfully installed Ruby in my windows 10 and also the shopify CLI in my OS but when I am trying to connect with my app using

```
shopify connect
```

It's throwing some error.I am not able to figure out the issues. This is the error thrown when I am trying to connect to shopify app using the Shopify CLI command.

```
[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify App CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- webrick
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify App CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- webrick
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/oauth.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:87:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:81:in `block in access_token'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/db.rb:87:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:80:in `access_token'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:74:in `api_client'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:49:in `block in query'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:63:in `authenticated_req'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api.rb:48:in `query'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/partners_api/organizations.rb:22:in `fetch_with_app'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/tasks/ensure_env.rb:28:in `fetch_org'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/tasks/ensure_env.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/task.rb:7:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/commands/connect.rb:44:in `default_connect'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/project_types/node/commands/connect.rb:10:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/sub_command.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/commands/connect.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/command.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/commands/connect.rb:9:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/stdout_router.rb:169:in `with_id'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:36:in `block in with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:172:in `log_output_to'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:35:in `with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:15:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:44:in `block in with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:43:in `with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:14:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/core/executor.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:43:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/core/monorail.rb:32:in `log'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:42:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:33:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in `handle_abort'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.5.0/bin/shopify:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I think this issues with Ruby latest version, you need to try with version 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue discussed over the `Ruby` and `Jekyll` forum also suggests the same solution.
[Link](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/load-error-cannot-load-such-file-webrick/5417)

[image]